# How to get the first elements of object arrays in a list with jxpath?

Tags: java, jxpath

```
List alma = new ArrayList();
alma.add(new Object[] { "alma", "korte" });
alma.add(new Object[] { "alma2", "korte2" });
alma.add(new Object[] { "alma3", "korte3" });
JXPathContext context = JXPathContext.newContext(alma);
List result = context.selectNodes("????????");
System.out.println(result);
```

So basically what should I write into the place of question marks to see the following output:

```
[alma,alma2,alma3]
```

Comment: Can you put your array list in some container object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. You need to put your data in some sort of container object. For example,

```
public class AlmaContainer {
  List<AlmaObject> alma = new ArrayList<AlmaObject>();
}

public class AlmaObject {
  String name;
  String value;
  AlmaObject(name, value) {
     this.name=name
     this.value= value
  }
}
```

And then you can use the following expression:

```
context.selectNodes("alma/@name");
```

Answer (score 0):

That's weird, but if you can't change your initial structure you can do it in 2 steps:

```
Iterator<Object> iter = context.iterate(".");
while(iter.hasNext()){
    Object o=iter.next();
    JXPathContext context2 = JXPathContext.newContext(o);
    System.out.println(context2.getValue(".[1]"));
}
```

Outputs:

```
alma
alma2
alma3
```